# Combine two list<> and remove the duplicates in it

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have two list objects. I combine them to a single list. Whilst combining I need to remove the duplicates. TweetID is the field to be compared.

```
List<TweetEntity> tweetEntity1 = tt.GetTweetEntity(Convert.ToInt16(pno), qdecoded, longwoeid );
List<TweetEntity> tweetEntity2 = tt.GetTweetEntity(Convert.ToInt16(pno), qdecoded);
List<TweetEntity> tweetEntity = tweetEntity1.Concat(tweetEntity2).ToList();
```

I have combined the two lists but unable to filter out the duplicates. Is there any inbuilt function to remove the duplicates in List<>?

Comment: Have you tried searching for an answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4031262/how-to-merge-2-listt-with-removing-duplicate-values-in-c-sharp http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3682437/combining-2-lists-and-and-remove-duplicates-output-in-a-third-list-my-attempts

Comment: This is not duplicate as here the list item is itself a complex object. The answers in the link are simple list of integer objects.

Comment: Same idea, except you have to consider searching for properties instead of just the value. You're allowed to extrapolate more complexity from a question.

Answer (score 6):

You could make use of `Union` method.

```
List<TweetEntity> tweetEntity = tweetEntity1.Union(tweetEntity2).ToList();
```

However, you have at first override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` for `TweetEntity`.

Comment: Or pass an `IEqualityComparer`, since equality may already have been implemented.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Distinct()` method.

```
tweetEntity1.Concat(tweetEntity2).Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: Using `Union` is the better approach, because this method already filters out duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

use the [`Union`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb341731(v=vs.100).aspx) linq extension,

```
tweetEntity1.Union(tweenEntity2).ToList()
```

functionally equivalent to `.Concat` and `Distinct` combined but easier to type and faster to run,

Answer (score 0):

You can use the linq `Distinct` method, however you'll have to implement `IEqualityComparer<T>`.

```
public class TweetEntityComparer<TweetEntity> 
{
    public bool Equals(TweetEntity x, TweetEntity y)
    {
        //Determine if they're equal
    }

    public int GetHashCode(TweetEntity obj)
    {
        //Implementation
    }
}

List<TweetEntity> tweetEntity = tweetEntity1.Concat(tweetEntity2).Distinct().ToList();
```

You could also alternatively use `Union`.

```
List<TweetEntity> tweetEntity = tweetEntity1.Union(tweetEntity2).ToList();
```

Comment: Union doesnot work. Since my list object is a class.

Comment: I donot know how to implement this IEqualityComparer<T>. Can you please elaborate.