# Left join on two Lists and maintain one property from the right with Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have 2 lists of the **same type**. The left list:

```
var leftList = new List<Person>();
leftList.Add(new Person {Id = 1, Name = "John", Changed = false});
leftList.Add(new Person {Id = 2, Name = "Alice", Changed = false});
leftList.Add(new Person {Id = 3, Name = "Mike", Changed = false});
```

And the right list:

```
var rightList = new List<Person>();
rightList.Add(new Person {Id = 1, Name = "John", Changed = false});
rightList.Add(new Person {Id = 3, Name = "Mike", Changed = true});
rightList.Add(new Person {Id = 4, Name = "Joshi", Changed = true});
```

I want to do a **left join**, but using the value on the `Changed` property from the **right**. Like this:

```
{Id = 1, Name = "John", Changed = false}
{Id = 2, Name = "Alice", Changed = false}
{Id = 3, Name = "Mike", Changed = true} // <-- true from the rightList
```

For this, I can't use simple [Left Join](https://stackoverflow.com/a/584840/5071902), and I cannot use a [Concat with GroupBy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3685033/5071902).

How can I do this with linq? Thanks.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This looks like a pretty standard left outer join scenario.

I always keep this extension method handy for left outer joins so I don't have to look up how to use the nasty query syntax (or remember wtf a GroupJoin is)...

```
public static class LinqEx
{
    public static IEnumerable<TResult> LeftOuterJoin<TOuter, TInner, TKey, TResult>(
        this IEnumerable<TOuter> outer, 
        IEnumerable<TInner> inner, 
        Func<TOuter, TKey> outerKeySelector, 
        Func<TInner, TKey> innerKeySelector, 
        Func<TOuter, TInner, TResult> resultSelector)
    {
        return outer
            .GroupJoin(inner, outerKeySelector, innerKeySelector, (a, b) => new
            {
                a,
                b
            })
            .SelectMany(x => x.b.DefaultIfEmpty(), (x, b) => resultSelector(x.a, b));
    }
}
```

Now you can:

```
leftList.LeftOuterJoin(
     rightList, 
     lft => lft.Id,
     rgt => rgt.Id,
     (lft, rgt) => new Person{Id = lft.Id, 
                              Name = lft.Name, 
                              Changed = rgt == null ? lft.Changed : rgt.Changed})
```

Comment: You'll get a nullref on the last line. Changed should be assigned `rgt == null ? lft.Changed : rgt.Changed`

Comment: @CameronMacFarland: Ta!

Comment: Hi spender thanks for your help, sorry about the delay, I was very busy here. Nice extension, thanks for sharing!

Comment: @RenanAraújo Hah! It's fine. Resharper pretty much wrote it for me!

Answer (score 7):

Why don't you try a solution like this:

```
var query = (from left in leftList
    join right in rightList on left.Id equals right.Id into joinedList
    from sub in joinedList.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new Person { 
        Id = left.Id,
        Name = left.Name,
        Changed = sub == null ? left.Changed : sub.Changed }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 4):

Well [spender](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14357/spender) was faster then me, I did without any extension method.

Without any extension method:

```
List<Person> mergedList =  leftList
            .GroupJoin(
                rightList, left => left.Id, right => right.Id, 
                (x, y) => new { Left = x, Rights = y  }
            )
            .SelectMany(
                x => x.Rights.DefaultIfEmpty(),
                (x, y) => new Person
                {
                    Id = x.Left.Id, 
                    Name = x.Left.Name, 
                    Changed = y == null ? x.Left.Changed : y.Changed
                }
            ).ToList();
```

The GroupJoin makes left outer join operation.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it would be:

```
//Step 1: Merge the lists while selecting the matching objects from rightList using Last()
var mergedList = leftList.Concat(rightList)
 .GroupBy(x => x.Id)
 .Select(x => x.Last());

//Step 2: Do a inner join between mergedList and leftList to get a left join result as originally required.
var innerJoinQuery = from mPerson in mergedList
                     join leftPerson in leftList on mPerson.Id equals leftPerson.Id
                     select new { Id = leftPerson.Id, Name = mPerson.Name, Changed = mPerson.Changed };
```