# IEqualityComparer and Linq Distinct - Hard Code GetHashCode()

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-objects

I have an array of `CustomObject` s and a custom `IEqualityComparer<CustomObject>`.  I have hard coded the `IEqualityComparer.GetHashCode()` method to return a constant `42`.

When I run linq's `Distinct` method on the array, nothing is filtered out.  Anyone know why?

*Note:* I know there are a number of questions on here about this issue, however, the ones I've seen ([C# Distinct on IEnumerable<T> with custom IEqualityComparer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432829/c-sharp-distinct-on-ienumerablet-with-custom-iequalitycomparer), [Distinct() with lambda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1300088/distinct-with-lambda), etc) only say to make sure to implement `GetHashCode`.  None of them explain, *why it doesn't work*.

Code:

```
public class CustomObject
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class CustomObjectEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<CustomObject>
{
    public bool Equals(CustomObject x, CustomObject y)
    {
        //Every CustomObject should now be 'equal'!
        return x.GetHashCode() == y.GetHashCode();
    }

    public int GetHashCode(CustomObject obj)
    {
        //Every CustomObject should now be 'equal'!
        return 42;
    }
}
```

Test:

```
[TestFixture]
public class TestRunner
{
    private CustomObject[] customObjects = 
    {
        new CustomObject {Name = "Please"},
        new CustomObject {Name = "Help"},
        new CustomObject {Name = "Me"},
        new CustomObject {Name = "Stack"},
        new CustomObject {Name = "Overflow"},
    };

    [Test]
    public void DistinctTest()
    {
        var distinctArray =
            customObjects.Distinct(new CustomObjectEqualityComparer()).ToArray();

        //Since every CustomObject is 'Equal' there should only be
        //1 element in the array.
        Assert.AreEqual(1, distinctArray.Length);
    }
}
```

This is the output I get from running the test:

```
 Expected: 5
 But was:  1
```

If I debug the test, I can see that `GetHashCode` is being called, so why isn't `Distinct` filtering out all the 'duplicates'?

Comment: If it is relevant, I'm using `.net 4.5.1`

Comment: Simple, you are calling `GetHashCode` on the `CustomObject` during equality, not calling your hardcoded version. The `Distinct` implementation is what uses the custom comparer. It will first call `GetHashCode`. If there is a collision, it will then call `Equals`, which you have no overridden on `CustomObject` so will be a reference hash code.

Comment: But I am passing in my `CustomObjectEqualityComparer`.  Comparison should be delegated to this class, right?

Comment: Damn it, after reading Jon Skeet's response I see it now, you are right @AdamHouldsworth.  Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> When I run linq's Distinct method on the array, nothing is filtered out. Anyone know why?

Yes - `Equals` is going to return `false` for any two distinct objects. Within your `Equals` implementation, you're calling the `CustomObject.GetHashCode` method (which isn't overridden), *not* your custom comparer's `GetHashCode` method. If you expected `Equals` to call your custom `GetHashCode` method, you'd need to change it to:

```
public bool Equals(CustomObject x, CustomObject y)
{
    return GetHashCode(x) == GetHashCode(y);
}
```

Or given the implementation of `GetHashCode(CustomObject)`, you can just simplify it to:

```
public bool Equals(CustomObject x, CustomObject y)
{
    return true;
}
```

Note that your `GetHashCode` method *was* being called by `Distinct()`, but it was then calling your `Equals` method to check that the objects were really equal... and at that point you were saying that they weren't (barring a massive coincidence).

Comment: Yup that did it.  Thanks Jon!

Comment: As a side question, is there a thread on here already about why `GetHashCode()` and `Equals()` both need to be called by `Distinct`?  I can understand `GetHashCode()` being used to put the objects into a `HashTable`, but can't `Distinct` assume if the Hash is equal the object is equal?

Comment: @ppittle No, it works the other way, that two objects of a different hash are *not* equal (which is subtly different from stating two objects with the same hash are equal). Collisions will happen because hashing narrows the range of available values, so `Equals` is then used afterwards to test for true equality. It is a performance / accuracy trade-off that works very well when you don't get too many collisions.